# Unable to open PhpMyadmin from Cpanel

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to delete some records from DB through querying from phpmyadmin, i successfully logged in through cPanel, i can take backup of database, I have access to all controls but when i click on phpmyadmin i get below error.

"Access Denied

Unable to establish a PHP session.

If you believe that this is in error or inadvertent, contact your system administrator and ask them to review your server settings."

Aany help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Regards,
MK

Comment: Sounds like you have some permission errors. I'm assuming you're dealing with a remote host since you're using cPanel, right?

Comment: Why not try accessing it through a browser?

Comment: I have added my ip to RemoteMysql but getting the same issue. this user need more permissions or we are missing some configurations?
I am new to PHP please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue of my shared hosting package.

```
Access Denied

Unable to establish a PHP session.

The account must be able to write to the php session directory and must not exceed the assigned disk quota.

If you believe that this is in error or inadvertent, contact your system administrator and ask them to review your server settings.
```

First check your Cpanel

```
Warning: This account has reached its disk usage quota. If you need more disk space, contact your service provider.
```

This will display like this so you have to  remove the unwanted files and clean the disk and increase the disk space and try again then that will worked fine

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

Just go to cPanel and change it's password.

This will sync the password of PhpMyAdmin with the new master password of cPanel and you will be able to enter PhpMyAdmin from cPanel again.

Answer (score 0):

I did a Google search for your error message and found that the cPanel forums suggest checking the permissions of your `/tmp` directory, check that they're set to 1777.

See also https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/unable-to-establish-a-php-session.414562/